# What version of iOS will I get on new iPad 4 Mini

Tags: ios, ipad

I would like to jailbreak my soon to be new iPad 4 Mini. Should I assume that it would still have iOS 9 installed when I get it out of the box?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for anyone here to give you a definitive answer to that question. Although the iPad mini 4 originally shipped with iOS 9.0 (13A340), it also fully supports the latest iterations of iOS 11.

In a nutshell, you should not assume that the one you buy will have iOS 9 as the version of iOS it has pre-installed will depend on when it was manufactured. Because of this, if it is *new*, it's likely to have a version of either iOS 10 or iOS 11.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. It's a bummer but at least the bummer I'd be aware of ...

Comment: One more thing ... were all versions of iOS eventually jailbreakable up till this point?

Comment: Yes, basically. There's actually a jailbreak that worked for beta versions of iOS 11, although I don't *think* that's available yet for final versions of iOS 11. What you can jailbreak can depend on the device, as well as the version of OS. And sometimes a jailbreak may work for 64-bit devices but not 32-bit, and so on. The reality is that the jailbreak community is not as active as it once was (a combination of iOS offering many of the functions people used to jailbreak for, and also because of the inherent risks of jailbreaking). If you have to jailbreak, than likely you can at some point.

Answer (score 2):

If the unit is still factory sealed, you can look up its production week by serial number and extrapolate the iOS build currently on it from there. With that said, a unit with iOS 9 might be a bit tough to come by at this point. You might have better luck trying for iOS 10 instead, although it's not clear to me whether this is an option for you.

Regardless, [*SarahB* from /r/jailbreak outlined this process here](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/3ulu3l/tutorial_wanna_buy_a_new_iphone_instore_this_is):

> 1. Check on this [Wiki](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Firmware) the date, when the last *non-jailbreakable* iOS version was released.
>    So, for the iPhone 6S / 6S Plus this would be 9.1 which Apple released
>    on 21/10/2015 (US: 10/21/2015 or 21st of October 2015 :)
> 2. We have to check the week number of the given date. We learn [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php) that 21/10/2015 occurred during **week 43**. We now know that every iPhone produced before week 43 comes 100% with < iOS 9.1 and can be jailbroken. There's a very high chance that even iPhones produced in week 43/44 will come with a jailbreakable firmware but go with a lower week if you want to be sure.
> 3. Now we enter the serial number  in [this
>    website](http://www.chipmunk.nl/klantenservice/applemodel.html) which
>    will reveal the production week number:
>
> [image]
>
> Here's an example what it looks like for my iPhone 6:
> [image]
>
> According to the wiki page above it has been originally shipped with iOS 8.0.x
> and can be jailbroken. Yay ;)
>
> 4. You now have to insist in the shop to check the serial numbers until you find the right one. This method works for iPhones / iPads and most likely for other iDevices too.

I had walked through this process myself with an iPhone 6S Plus and can confirm it still gives valid information. An iPad Mini 4 would likely work as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, a new iPad will have a new iOS version, probably 11.

Comment: It's conceivable that the iPad could have left the factory before the release of iOS 11, but it will certainly be at least iOS 10, assuming it's been bought from a normal retailer.